# Rewrite works for directories. But not for files

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

My code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^article/([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=article&name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

This works. But if I supply a filename or directory, it fails.

What i want:

- redirect to home page, if user requests a directory or filename.
- else, this rule should be evaluated:

  `RewriteRule ^article/([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=article&name=$1 [L]`
  `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]`

There is one index.php file at root of my site: "http://mysite.com/index.php"

Sample requests:

```
User typed url  --- Physical matched url  ---  Comments
----------------------------------------------------------

http://mysite.com/cinema    ---   http://mysite.com/index.php?page=cinema  --- display     cinema page
http://mysite.com/contacus    ---   http://mysite.com/index.php?page=contactus  ---     display contact us page
http://mysite.com/article/iphone    ---   http://mysite.com/index.php?page=article&name=iphone  --- display article
http://mysite.com/images    ---   http://mysite.com/index.php  --- redirect to index page, because it is a physical directory
http://mysite.com/js    ---   http://mysite.com/index.php  --- redirect to index page, because it is a physical directory
```

My partially working code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ / [R,L]

RewriteRule ^article/([a-z]+)/?$  /index.php?page=article&name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

If i use above code, it works partially. That is,

```
http://mysite.com/images  --- http://mysite.com/?page=images is displayed in address bar
http://mysite.com/images/  --- http://mysite.com/ is displayed in address bar
```

When I use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` as second condition (after first condition's line), it will not work.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Surely your rewrite rules should only be applied if a file or directory does *not* exist?

Try using these lines as your `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: thankyou but that did not worked. I am now mentally depressed because of this simple problem. My whole script works without any problems but only this url rewriting is causing problem. I have been spending several hours now to find solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

Tried it on my localhost, and this worked properly:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^article/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=article&name=$1 [L]

# For Future Reference, this works well for the final RewriteRule
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

As an alternate solution, you could also rewrite all the urls to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L]
```

The first RewriteRule will actually redirect the browser, but the second one will just translate it. The upside to this is that index.php will receive the REQUEST_URI of the original url:

```
$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // array( 0 => 'article', 1 => 'iphone', 2 => '')
```